# How do you set a has_one default value in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

user = User.new
user.profile.something #=> ERROR
```

What is a proper way to set a default profile object in this case?  I have tried this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :include => :profile
  has_one :profile

  def after_initialize
    self.profile ||= Profile.new(:user => self)
  end
end
```

...but that creates N+1 queries.  Any ideas?

**Update**

This is what I have now, works okay, still looking for something better:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :include => :profile
  has_one :profile, :autosave => true

  def after_initialize
    self.profile = Profile.new(:user => self) if new_record?
  end
end
```

This way, you're going to have a Profile whenever you finally `create` your user.  Otherwise, the only case is a `new_record?`.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own User#profile that will build one for you if it doesn't exist:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  def profile_with_default
    profile_without_default || build_profile
  end
  alias_method_chain :profile, :default
end
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17826006/18706) is a good answer:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :preference_set

 def preference_set
   super || build_preference_set
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer relies on what are your intentions, cause there is no straight forward solution to this kind of problem.

The after_initialize callback is called after object is instantiated, so it's not really a good place for this kind of logic.

Maybe you should try to use before_create / after_create instead? Those callbacks are called only at object creation time.

Also, don't use Profile.new, use one of the methods below instead:

```
self.build_profile(...)
self.create_profile(...)
```

In the 2nd case the model is being saved. You can pass a hash with model attributes to both methods (don't pass :user, as it is set automatically).

Comment: I'm thinking about those, but actually for my specific case, the profile class depends on the subclass: `class Admin < User`, so `build_profile` has to build `"#{self.class.name}Profile".constantize.new`.  I'm using something this for Group, RealEstate, and User.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is good. I've got a slightly different solution:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :include => :profile
  has_one :profile
  alias_method :my_profile, :profile

  def my_profile
    self.profile = Profile.create(:user => self) unless self.profile
    self.profile
  end
end
```

**Good**

- create profile when requested, not on instantiation

**Not so good**

- You have to use `my_profile` (or however you would like to call it)
- The `unless self.profile` check has to be done on each profile call

Comment: thanks, but I'm not a big fan of aliasing methods like this, it makes subclassing and including modules more difficult to manage.