# Rails: Create association if none is found to avoid nil errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

I have an application where my users can have a set of preferences. Both are stored as ActiveRecord-models as follows:

```
class User < AR::Base
   has_one :preference_set
end

class PreferenceSet < AR::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I can now access the preferences of a user:

```
@u = User.first
@u.preference_set => #<PreferenceSet...>
@u.preference_set.play_sounds => true
```

But this fails if a preference set is not already created, since @u.preference_set will be returning nil, and I'll be calling `play_sounds` on `nil`.

What I want to archive is that User.preference_set always returns a PreferenceSet instance. I've tried defining it like this:

```
class User < ..
   has_one :preference_set

   def preference_set
     preference_set || build_preference_set
   end
end
```

This is causing a `'Stack level too deep'`, since it is calling itself recursively.

My question is this:

How can I ensure that `@user.preference_set` returns either the corresponding preference_set-record or, if none exists, builds a new one?

I know I could just rename my association (eg. `preference_set_real`) and avoid recursive calls this way, but for the sake of simplicity in my app, I'd like to keep the naming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well the best way to do this is to create the associated record when you create the primary one:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one       :preference_set, :autosave => true
   before_create :build_preference_set
end
```

That will set it up so whenever a `User` is created, so is a `PreferenceSet`. If you need to initialise the the associated record with arguments, then call a different method in `before_create` which calls `build_preference_set(:my_options => "here")` and then returns `true`.

You can then just normalise all existing records by iterating over any that don't have a `PreferenceSet` and building one by calling `#create_preference_set`.

If you want to only create the `PreferenceSet` when it is absolutely needed, then you can do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :preference_set

   def preference_set_with_initialize
     preference_set_without_initialize || build_preference_set
   end

   alias_method_chain :preference_set, :initialize
end
```

Comment: Be advised that `alias_method_chain` has been deprecated in favor of `Module#prepend`. More info here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19434

Answer (score 63):

There's an elegantly simple form:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :preference_set
  
  def preference_set
    super || build_preference_set
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord [intentionally enables](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Overriding+generated+methods) such use of `super` to override the behaviour of association methods.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.